# Input <M-e> with vim

Tags: vim

I'm on a mac terminal using the auto-pairs plugin. I'm trying to use the feature to wrap some text in parentheses. The manual says to use `<M-e>` but I do not know what this corresponds to on my keyboard. I've tried just about everything but nothing works. Google turns up nothing.

Comment: The keywords for searching on google are: "vim meta key apple" (/osx?). You'll see several answers from SO domain. Your question is probably a duplicate question, but as I don't use mac, I can't say which one is the right Q/A to point to. BTW, I don't even try to use meta-mappings in vim in terminal on Linux. It's quite complex to configure correctly. I'd suggest to either use macvim, or to look if your plugin permits to use other keybindings, or to try other bracketing/surrounding plugins (like lh-brackets that will surround with parenthesis on just `(`, or the surround plugin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Terminal.app…

- open the *Preferences* window,
- choose the *Profiles* tab,
- choose your current profile,
- under *Keyboard*, check "Use 'Option' key…".

In iTerm.app…

- open the *Preferences* window,
- choose the *Profiles* tab,
- choose your current profile,
- under *Keys*, choose which *option* key you want to use as *Meta* and check *+Esc*.

In your `vimrc`, add the line below to make it understand `<M-e>`:

```
set <M-e>=^[e
```

The `^[` is a literal `<Esc>` that you insert by typing `<C-v>` then `<Esc>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think "M" normally refers to either "Mod" (alt) or "Meta" (the apple key in your case). So it would either be alt-e or apple-e

Comment: The apple key is the command key. `Meta` should probably be the `option` key, just left to the command key.

Comment: Yeah it's been a while since i used apple myself, hence the confusion. Isn't "option" basically apple's name for the alt key though? Anyway, i guess i got "Meta" confused with "Super" :)

Comment: When I hit Option-E, I get a little backtick that shows up but it doesn't wrap the text in parens.